# I can't access a variable in another class

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to access the localId variable in the MyFirebase class from another class but it keeps telling me that there is no such file like that in the MyFirebase class, im trying to print the value after a user logs in but it tells me it doesn't exist. can someone help and identify the problem. Below is my MyFirebase class and the class where I am trying to print the value from

```
class MyFireBase():

    def __init__(self):
        self.localId = None


    def sign_up(self, email, password):

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(sign_up_request.ok)
            print(sign_up_request.content.decode())


            if sign_up_request.ok == True:
                print(sign_up_data)
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']

                # Save refreshToken to a file
                with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(refresh_token)


                app.local_id = self.localId
                app.id_token = idToken




                my_data =  '{"avatar": "profilepic.png", "jobs_done": "", "jobs_posted": ""}'
                post_request = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + self.localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken, data=my_data)
                print(post_request.ok)
                print(post_request.content.decode())

                app.root.current = "create"



            elif sign_up_request.ok == False:

                error_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
                error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
                app.root.ids.signup.ids.signup_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

    def send_user_details(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        my_data ={"first name": app.root.ids.create.ids.first_name.text, "last name": app.root.ids.create.ids.last_name.text,
                   "phone number": app.root.ids.create.ids.phone_number.text, "job1": app.root.ids.create.ids.job1.text, "job2": app.root.ids.create.ids.job2.text,
                   "job3": app.root.ids.create.ids.job3.text, "date of birth": app.root.ids.create.ids.date_of_birth.text, "state": app.root.ids.create.ids.state1.text}

        user_details = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + app.local_id + ".json?auth=" + app.id_token,  json.dumps(my_data))
        print(user_details.ok)
        print(user_details.content.decode())

        app.root.current = "main"




    def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
        signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
        signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(signin_request.ok)
        print(signin_request.content.decode())

        if signin_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
            # Save refreshToken to a file
            with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)

            # Save localId to a variable in main app class
            # Save idToken to a variable in main app class
            app.local_id = self.localId
            app.id_token = idToken
            # Create new key in database from localId
            # Get friend ID
            # Get request on firebase to get the next friend id
            # --- User exists so i dont need to get a friend id
            # self.friend_get_req = UrlRequest("https://friendly-fitness.firebaseio.com/next_friend_id.json?auth=" + idToken, on_success=self.on_friend_get_req_ok)
            # app.change_screen("home_screen")

            app.root.current = "main"

        elif signin_request.ok == False:
            error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
            error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
            app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")
```

Here is the class im trying to print it from

```
class ProfileWindow(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(MyFireBase.localId)
```

Please can someone help me identify where I am getting it wrong, thank you

Comment: Because you define it in MyFireBase as `self.localId`, i is an instance variable not a class variable. So you first need to instantiate an object. `print(MyFireBase().localId` should work but a better way is something like `fire_base = MyFireBase()` and then call `fire_base.localId`. Alternatively you can define `localId = None` outside the `__init__` function and then it will be available as a class variable.

Comment: Random article explaining the difference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3

Comment: You're confusing instance and class variables, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the value from a class instance, you'll have to supply the instance. Otherwise use `MyFireBase().localId`
If you want the value after any changes to default, use this:

```
class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, fb, **kwargs)
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.firebase = fb

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.firebase.localId)

"""
WHILE ADDING TO SCREEN MANAGER:
"""
fb = MyFireBase()
screenmanager.add_widget(ProfileWindow(fb=fb))
```

NoneType Fix:
Add a getter in the first class and call the function from the second

```
class MyFireBase():
    ...
    def get_ID(self):
        return self.localId

class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, fb, **kwargs)
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.firebase = fb

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.firebase.get_ID())
```

The ... is the existing class, Add the function to the bottom of the class declaration. Issue might have been that the value may not have gotten changed. Although first should first, This alternate fix might help if that isn't.

Comment: ive solved that problem, but now the localId is a Nonetype object. I've tried so many times to make it return the value but it doesn't work

Comment: it works when I try to print it in the firebase class but not in any other class

Comment: I added a small extension to it. Try it now, should work.

Comment: im getting an error adding the widget to screen manager and when I skip that, im getting this error on the print function `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_ID' `

Comment: Bro appreciate you taking your time to help me

Comment: Try removing the `firebase = StringProperty('')` line

Comment: this error bro `AttributeError: 'ProfileWindow' object has no attribute 'myfirebase'`